# What happens if I add same view from interface builder ? - iPhone

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, addsubview

I created a 3 view in interface builder.
I was supposed to show views on click event.
What happens if write

[self.view addSubView:view1];

in click event.
And am not removing this anywhere.
Finally releasing this in Dealloc.

Please give suggestion if this is a leak...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Then view1 becomes a subview of self.view. There is no leak. If it's already a subview of self.view, it will first be removed and then added back.

Why don't you try it and see for yourself?

Comment: view linked with another object. This object belongs to another viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

It will show your view1 as it is default frontview.
If you not removing then it will be there in memory..

Comment: Yes but am using this view with another object. This object belongs to another viewcontroller

Comment: I was supposed to use three UIViews in one UIViewController.